# How to group by two cols with special case

Tags: sql

The input data is:
Data format is:
(Class, type, name),
Data is:

```
(1, a, p1)
(1, b, p2)
(1, c, p3)
(2, a, p4)
```

From the above data I need to produce.

I want to group data by (class and type).
But type=a and type=b should be count in one group.
So,

```
p1 and p2 is one group, 
p3 is one group, 
p4 is ome group.
```

The output should be:
Data format is:
(Class, count).
Data is:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
```

Can someone help me to do this in SQL please?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `case`

```
select 
    class, count(*)
from 
    table_name
group by 
    class, case when type_col in ('a','b') then 'a' else type_col end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `case` to combine the groups:

```
select class, (case when type in ('a', 'b') then 'combined' else type end) as grp,
       count(*)
from t
group by class, (case when name in ('a', 'b') then 'combined' else type end)
```

You don't need to put the `grp` column in the `select`.  I think the output is clearer with this information.